# Why can't I visualize objects in chunks of html output

Tags: html, output, r-markdown, knitr, broken-links

[image]I used knitr to make html page (it's a blog) from Rmarkdown  but I can't see objects (for instance a histogram when I digit the name of the object in the chunk) and I see the broken link instead

```
y <- rnorm(100,1,5)
hist(y)
```

Comment: Show us the complete chunk or even better your RMD file.

Comment: That's the Chunk basically, the most rmd file is just text so no relevant codes. I think it is a problem with the server? I also tried to upload on the server the images deriving from these chunks (like above) but still broken link

Comment: do you have the {r} at the beginning of your chunk?

Comment: yes I do have it, and I can see the histogram when I open the html output, the problem is when I open It on the server.

Comment: it is difficult to guess without your complete RMD file.